# Firefox WebExtension CSP Issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to convert  a Chrome extension into  Firefox WebExtension. Its worked out fine so far, but for some reason, I'm facing an issue with GitHub. My Extension adds a small div to the side of the page, but when I try to add it to GitHub, I get the error

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("script-src https://assets-cdn.github.com").

I'm not sure why though, because in my `manifest.json` I have set the CSP to be

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'; font-src 'self' data:;"
```

I'd appreciate any advice on this issue. Its working fine on Chrome as is.

Comment: I asked the folk in #webextensions and they mentioned that while we don't allow `unsafe-inline` in firefox, it seems the CSP issue is related more to Github then to the addon.

Comment: The same CSP works on Chrome so why not on Firefox :(

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].